# Can I get Data from mongodb and MySQL same time for designing reports in power bi?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, powerbi

I wanted to get Data from mongodb and MySQL and design report using both db's data. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you need a basic Power BI introduction or what is the problem here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.